# Outliner for java files

Tags: eclipse, rascal

With the help of util::IDE library it is possible to create your own IDE features in Eclipse e.g. outliners or annotators. The documentation shows an example of how to do this for your own language. But how can this be done with Java files?

```
registerAnnotator("java", Tree (Tree t) { return t[@doc="Hello!"]; });
```

I tried with above code as I thought I didn't have to register the java language. Or is still needed to create my own Java grammar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We did not wire contributions to the Java IDE in Eclipse indeed. That would be a nice feature request, however pretty hard to make happen since the JDT is so tangled and coupled with itself.

You could use the Java grammar in the library, which supports up to Java 6. It would need some extending for Java 8 and Java 9, and you could wire the builder as well using the M3 mapping to show error messages and warnings and such. This will also give you the opportunity to write your own outliner.

Comment: Isn't there a way to open a file with certain lines highlighted?

Comment: yes, from `util::Editors`, but that wouldn't trigger on safe or something.